# The expected value of a Max function

Tags: expected-value, maxima-minima

U=max(0,x)

where x=a with probability q and b with probability 1-q.

I saw someone write:

$E(U)=\max(0,E(x))=\max(0,aq+(1-q)b)$

To me this looks wrong, am I right?

I would think it should be:
$E(U)=q \max (0,a)+ (1-q) \max (0,b)$

They are identical if $a,b>0$. But not necessarily otherwise. For example if $b=-a$, and $q=1/2$, according to the first formula, $E(U)=0$.

But according to the latter:

$E(U)=\frac{1}{2} \max (0,a)+ \frac{1}{2} \max (0,-a)=\frac{a}{2}$

The former or the latter?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Expected value does *not* distribute through the max function, since the latter is not linear.

The person who wrote $E(U) = \max(0,E(x))$ must have been confused.